# Flow: access to object fields

Tags: visual-workflow

I want to build a flow and specify conditions : if object.field equals 'value' etc...
When I select Decision, and look under Resource, I do not have access to Object fields.

How do I access them in order to base the Outcome based on the values ?

[image: My Flow]

Comment: what kind of flow is this?

Comment: Autolaunched.But I get the same thing when I select Record triggered and add a Decision after the initial Start conditions.

Comment: You need to [edit] the question to explicitly state the type of flow and to show the base flow screen. You should be seeing `$Record` in your condition editing if you have the right type of flow with the base parameters correctly defined (such as which object it is for).

Comment: see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_type.htm&type=5 for list of flow types